# parcel build building in root folder instead of ./dist

Tags: build, package.json, parcel

I am very confused as to why my parcel build script is spewing everything into the root folder instead of into `./dist`, I have tried specifying with and without output paths with no luck.

What confuses me more is how my `start` script `"parcel index.html"` outputs into the `dist` folder.

To clarify on the below, I am running: `npm run build`

Here's my package.json

Thank you for any help!

```json
{ 
  "name": "eclaires","version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "browserslist": "last 10 versions",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss css/style.comp.css --use autoprefixer -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass prefix:css compress:css",
    "build:html": "parcel build index.html --dist-dir ./dist",
    
    "build": "npm-run-all build:css build:html"
  },
  "author": "LY",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "postcss": "^8.2.6",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `"main": "index.html"` from _package.json_, then run `npm run build` - as suggested in [issue #5063](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/5063)?

Comment: It throws an error on build, after quite a while of looking up I found the use of "default" instead of "main", which seems to have fixed the issue. Although I don't actually know why it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, use the [`--dist-dir <dir>`](https://parceljs.org/features/cli/#parameters) option during build:

```bash
parcel build index.js --dist-dir ./dist
```

or specify the build directory for your project at `package.json#main`.

```json
{
  "main": "dist/index.js"
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build"
  }
}
```

Your `main` is set to the root `index.html`, which is why it is output there.

Also, the reason why running your `npm start` outputs to `dist` but your `npm build` outputs to root is because your start script is set to:

> `"start": "parcel index.html",`

which is equivalent to Parcel's default `serve` command:

`parcel serve index.html`

Parcel's `serve` command may behave differently than `build`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not setting up the output directory.

According to the documentation, you can do like I did below, this will create the dist folder and the files:

https://parceljs.org/cli.html

```html
{
  "name": "silicia",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "parcel": "^1.12.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.32.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html --out-dir ./dist"
  },
  "author": "Jesus Ramirez",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```